# Отправка запроса после появления сети в Robospice+retrofit

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, robospice

Добрый день!
У меня есть класс запроса:

```
    public static class ValuesRequest extends RetrofitSpiceRequest<Response, Api> {
    String mAuth;
    public ValuesRequest(String basic_auth_string64) {
        super(Response.class, Api.class);
        mAuth=basic_auth_string64;
    }

    @Override
    public Response loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
        return getService().values(mAuth);
    }
}
```

Который выполняется во фрагменте, на нажатию кнопки отправить.

```
    ((BaseActivity) activity).getSpiceManager().execute(valuesRequest, new PendingRequestListener<Response>() {...}
```

Данный запрос должен выполниться сразу (при наличии доступа в интернет), либо как только такой доступ появится.

Есть ли у Robospice штатный механизм реализации такой логики запроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько мне известно, стадартно такого нет. Но дописать будет не очень сложно.

Comment: Я предположил, что такая возможность, потому, что robospice требует android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE в манифесте.

Comment: это разрешение требуется для того, чтобы перед отправкой запроса, проверить наличие сети. Если сети нет, то кинется соответствующее исключение.